# Select my sql database doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

I just wanted to create a code (WALL POST) where i can only see the post from my friends ordered by 'feedid' but it isnt ordered by 'feedid'... What should I do??

```
<?php
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$from12 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE username = '$user'");
if(mysql_num_rows($from12) != 0){
    $from = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE username = '$user'");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($from))
    {
       $from1 = $row2->friend;
       $files = glob('lang/'. $lang .'.xml');
       foreach($files as $file){
           $ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feed WHERE username = '$from1' ORDER BY feedID DESC");
           while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
           {
               echo' <div class="panel"><a href="user.php?lang='. $lang .'&user='. $row->username .'"><strong>'. $row->username .'</strong></a> ('.$row->date.'):<br/> '. $row->text .'<a href="com.php?id='. $row->feedID .'&lang='. $lang .'"><img src="'.$row->pic.'"></a><br/><a href="com.php?id='. $row->feedID .'&lang='. $lang .'">'. $xml->reply .'</a></div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
  echo'';
}
?>
```

Comment: What you mean by it doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: no it isnt ordered by feedid

Comment: Can we see an example of the output?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and an output of a query result?

Comment: yes of course :): http://www.us4r.com

Comment: You're performing a couple of queries; the first selects all friends, and the second selects all posts from one friend, ordered by feedid - that second query is performed for each friend, so the ordering is lost. You should be able to re-do your queries so it's done in just one call.

Comment: username: test Password: test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing two queries (well, three, but the first one is done twice)

The second query gets the updates, but it's run separately for each friend. You need to combine the two for the ORDER to work. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    feed 
WHERE 
    username IN (SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE username='$username') 
ORDER BY feedID DESC
```

You'll have to tweak the logic of your code, but something like that statement should fetch everything in one go.

ObNote - you should switch to using PDO or mysqli for your database connections, as they're a lot more secure. Also, I've not tested the above, but it should at least give you the right idea.